# Android Pre-installing NDK Application

Tags: android, android-ndk

We are trying to pre-install a NDK Application into the `/system/app` directory. If I open the apk file in a ZIP file manager, the `.so` file is inside the lib directory. However, when we preinstall the `apk` file, the apk's `.so` file is not copied to `system/lib` directory, causing for the application to fail when we launched it in the device.

Can anyone please tell me what should be set in the `Android.mk` for the APK file so that the `.so` file will be extracted from the APK file and copied to `system/lib` directory? We need to include the application in the system image.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Comment: Technically, I believe the .so file should be copied to the /data/data/com.yourpackage.name/lib directory, but I am having the same problem in the pre-installed apps are not copying this out of the APK.

Comment: what we did is we just unzipped the so file from APK manually using any zip tools like 7zip. Then, we created a make file that will copy the files to /out/..../system/lib directory while compiling the android source code. In our case we would like to include it in the ROM image since it is needed by a native app, that is why we need to copy it to /system/lib directory.

Comment: you can refer to this forum https://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/2d08a95b3038e532?hl=ja
 they had the same problem as ours

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's by design.  I'm testing today whether placing it in the data/app directory (another location that will be automatically unpacked) has the same effect.  If it works, I may post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same need and after 2 days of heavy research, I came up with a solution to this problem. It is not simple and requires you to be able to modify the Android System code as well.

Basically PackageManagerService prevents system applications to unpack their native binaries (.so files), unless they have been updated. So the only way to fix this is by modifying PMS.java (aptly named since trying to solve this problem put me in a terrible mood).

On the system's first boot, I check every system package for native binaries by writing a isPackageNative(PackageParser.Package pkg) function:

```
    private boolean isPackageNative(PackageParser.Package pkg) throws IOException {
    final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(pkg.mPath);
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> privateZipEntries = zipFile.entries();
    while (privateZipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = privateZipEntries.nextElement();
        final String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();
        if(true) Log.e(TAG, "    Zipfile entry:"+zipEntryName);
        if (zipEntryName.endsWith(".so")) {
            zipFile.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    zipFile.close();
    return false;
  }
```

This function checks every package for a native library and if it has one, I unpack it. PMS does this check in scanPackageLI(....). Search for the following code in the method:

```
   if (isSystemApp(pkg) && !isUpdatedSystemApp(pkg))
```

and add the isPackageNative(pkg) check. There are other small modifications required but you'll probably figure it out once you have this direction. Hope it helps!

Comment: wow thanks! this is so far the best answer although I don't have a chance to try it for now. but it looks like the best way to do it so I'll accept this as the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot do it by default as Android's /system partition is mounted as read-only! You need a rooted phone so as to mount the /system with write privileges through this command:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system.
```

So, if you have a rooted phone you can add in your application this code:

```
Process p;  
try {  
    // Preform su to get root privledges
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    // Attempt to write a file to a root-only  
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
    // gain root privileges 
    os.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
    // do here the copy operation you want in /system/lib file, for example:
    os.writeBytes("mv /sdcard/mylib.so /system/lib/\n");

     // Close the terminal  
     os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
     os.flush();  

 } catch (IOException e) {  
    toastMessage("could not get root access");  
 }
```

Otherwise, you have to follow the solution that digitalmouse12 gave..

Comment: This is not truly relevant, as you are talking about modifying the installation on a phone, but the poster is talking about including something in the system image to be installed, before it is installed on the phone.

Comment: Thank you Thanasis. However, Chris is correct. What I wanted to know is how to pre-install a prebuilt apk file with bundled .so files into the system image.

Comment: Yes right, now I understand the problem but I don't know the solution.. If I find something I'll let you know! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to "adb push" the `.so` file yourself. Also, you don't necessarily have to push your library into `system/lib` (the folder might deny you permission anyway). Most push it to `data/app` and then load by issuing

```
System.load("/data/app/<libName>.so");
```

Comment: thanks @digitalmouse12 for your comment. However, we need to integrate the application into the system image meaning we have to pre-install it without using adb.

Comment: I found this post [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/aff028eff3d680a4/342691bc1145389a?lnk=gst&q=boot+so+apk#342691bc1145389a), and it says there that "During the very first boot sequence (e.g. after a -wipe-data when starting the emulator, or a factory reset on a device), the system will scan for bundled applications under /system/app/<packagename>.apk, and will install them one by one.".

Comment: Does it also mean that the library files (*.so) will be extracted to the /system/lib directory? But why it also says there that "Applications that are bundled with the system _should_ place their system libraries under /system/lib"?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably documentation somewhere, but if you cannot find that, I would suggest identifying a pre-installed app with an associated jni library .so and examining the android sources or corresponding system image or update.zip to see how it's handled.

In other words, programming by example...